# What is the better java coding practice?

Tags: java, methods

I got the below question for an assignment in my Java class.

**Write a Java method to find & print the area of a circle when user input the radius.**

I came up with 2 solutions,

**Solution 1**: Call a void method where the method does all the inputs and calculations and prints the output.

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
   public static void area(){
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      double area = 0;
      double radius = input.nextInt();
      area = 3.14 * radius * radius;
      System.out.println("Area is: " + area);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println("Input the radius: ");
      area();
   }
}
```

**Solution 2**: Call a parameterized double method. Here the input is fed to the main method and calculation is done in the double method and value is returned back to the main method.

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
   public static double area(double r){
      double area = 0;
      area = 3.14 * r * r;
      return area;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println("Input the radius: ");
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      double radius = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Area is: " + area(radius));
   }
}
```

I am wondering what is the best coding practice. Solution 1 or 2 and why is that? Thanks in advance for all the responses.

Comment: Solution #2. You can re-use that function with data from sources other than just stdin. For example: a file or maybe in a GUI program.

Comment: Define "best": lines of code, runtime complexity, memory usage, maintainability, points during exam, time to market, testability, aesthetics, …? I have a favorite (it's solution 2), but this question is purely _opinion-based_ and as such off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: I've voted to close as opinion based.  But the right answer is #2.  One method should have one responsibility; but  the  `area()` method in solution #1 does three different things - the input, the calculation and the output.

Comment: Solution 2. The design principle you are looking for her that justifies this choice is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

You might even take it further and separate out reading user input from the main function.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second version is better because it separates the concerns of (a) calculating the area from (b) what to do with the results.

You don't need to declare `double area = 0` before you assign a value to it. You can simply write:

```
double area = 3.14 * r * r;
```

But, in fact, you don't need to declare a variable at all in that method. You can return the value.

```
public static double area(double r){
    return 3.14 * r * r;
}
```

You can also use the Math constant for PI:

```
public static double areaOfCircle(double r){
    return Math.PI * r * r;
}
```